# Launch Anconda3 from backup

Tags: python, anaconda, yaml, conda, environment

Tried running Anaconda back up on new computer from bash but it did not work. So I downloaded Anaconda3 again.

I have a backup from my stolen computer. I can see **anaconda3** folder and inside I can find **envs** folder. Inside there is a folder for each of my environments. Unfortunately when I open the specific environment folders, I cannot find any .yml file. Note: I never exported any environment to yml file before.

Unfortunately, I cannot import any of my former environments, as I cannot find any .yml/yaml file.

Can anyone shed some light on how to find or generate a yml file from backed up environments (inside envs folder)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One should be able to activate the environments by using the *prefix* (path):

```bash
conda activate /path/to/the/backup/anaconda3/envs/foo
```

One way to possibly recreate them on the new system would be through cloning. For example,

```bash
conda create --clone /path/to/the/backup/anaconda3/envs/foo -n foo
```

Or you can do as suggested and dump YAMLs:

```bash
## use the `-p` (prefix) flag to specify by path
conda env export -p /path/to/the/backup/anaconda3/envs/foo > foo.yaml
```

Alternatively, if the backup is going to be permanently mounted, the location could be added to `envs_dirs`, and this should re-enable referring to them by name:

```bash
## use `--append` so new environments are not created there
conda config --append envs_dirs /path/to/the/backup/anaconda3/envs
```

In practice, however, this may have issues resolving dynamically-linked libraries that used absolute paths. The cloning strategy might be better.

Comment: excellent, precise and really useful. Thank you @merv

Comment: The cloning method seems useful but it  does not work for me, since my PC username has changed.
To run an installed package like `ipython` in my environment , I normally would just run a command (i.e. `ipython`) which runs a bash file that will open the program.
The problem is that the first line of this bash script is something like `#!/path/to/old/environment/bin/python`. Since this path is not updated, bash returns a `bad interpreter` error.

Comment: @Miguel I just tested on my `jupyter` environment: `conda create --clone jupyter -n j2`. Checking `head envs/j2/bin/ipython` clearly shows it has been updated to the new directory. I.e., I can't recreate your issue.

Comment: I have re-done it just now, and it does not update for me. My Conda version is 23.1.0

Comment: @Miguel file a bug report