# Cloned environment causes Kernel to die on a jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, kernel, environment

I have just cloned an environment from an Anaconda3 backup.

When running Jupyter Notebook on new computer with cloned environment, Kernel dies. I keep receiving the following message:

"The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically"

The environment worked just fine on my stolen computer. Jupyter Notebooks are the same. No packages have been added to environment.

I would be grateful if anyone could shed some light on this.

Comment: Try not to transfer environments between computers. Create a new one!

Comment: @KlausD. I did clone it from my backup to new Anaconda3. Here is how : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67650749/launch-anconda3-from-backup/67661484#67661484

Comment: This is hard to diagnose without a `conda env export`. Perhaps the `conda create --clone` is not recreating properly. Try the `conda env export -p` instead and then recreate from that. If still not working, perhaps `ipykernel` needs to be updated in the env. Where are is Jupyter installed?

Comment: @merv I have activated environment from the anaconda3 backup directory, then did conda env export -p. Activated environment, later exported packages to .txt (conda list --explicit > pkgs.txt). Finally, created NEWENV from pkgs.txt. 
Updated ipykernell from conda.
Activated NEWENV, run jupyter notebook.... when running first cell, "kernell appears to die out"

Comment: So Jupyter is installed in this environment? Have you tried recreating from the `conda env export` using `conda env create`? I don’t think the `conda list --explicit` captures PyPI packages, if there are any. Does the notebook execute properly when activating the backup and running Jupyter? Perhaps add the YAML to the question. In general, please add requested information and additional steps you’ve taken to the question (edit it) rather than as comments. Comments would be for you to ask for clarification or ping me to look at the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information it's difficult to pinpoint the exact problem. Not sure if this is helpful but did you re-create the environment or was it a folder you copied from a backup disk? Conda environments work with absolute paths, so if you move the folder containing the env to a different location it will stop working. Even if you somehow restore from back-up, the paths to all the files in the env need to be identical as they were when the packages were installed. You can try [this](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#building-identical-conda-environments) to recreate your environment from scratch.

Comment: I did clone it. Here is how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67650749/launch-anconda3-from-backup/67661484#67661484

Comment: Have you tried to re-create from a file using `conda env create -f environment.yml` where you created the file with `conda env export > environment.yml` ?

Comment: A few other things you could try: 

* you have pip packages also in this environment which are now causing conflicts. You could try to install those packages from conda-forge instead for a more reliable environment.
* you can try to update the entire environment

Comment: on top of that, I did create a virtual environment conda create -n foo python=3.6 anaconda